# Asynchronous or Synchronous calling of event handlers in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, event-handling, synchronous

Are event handlers executed synchronously or asynchronously in JavaScript?
Here is [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/uvoqit/1/edit) which is showing that event handler is executed synchronously.

Code:

```
$('#toclick').bind('custom', function() {
    for (var i=0; i<100000; i++) {}
    console.log('Inside click handler');
});

$('#toclick').trigger('custom');
console.log('Outside click handler');
```

Output:

```
Inside click handler
Outside click handler
```

This means if we trigger an event, the code below it won't be executed unless all the event handlers are executed. Am I right ?

[Bin with multiple event handlers](http://jsbin.com/uvoqit/3/edit)

Comment: all events are synchronous. You might also like to a look into event propagation http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's correct. All event handlers are fired synchronously and in order of binding.

Comment: what do you think about the `Some event handlers are executed synchonously and others asynchronously.`?

Comment: @xianshenglu there's a confusion. Once an event is triggered all handlers bound to it run synchronously. But events (e.g. load) can be triggered asynchronously. So handlers are always synchronous. While events themselves need not. Note that `trigger` function triggers an event synchronously.

Answer (score 11):

Some event handlers are executed synchonously and others asynchronously.
See [DOM-Level-3-Events](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#sync-async)

Comment: The document outlines the events are fired either synchronously or asynchronously, but it doesn't specify whether the handlers themselves are executed synchronously. In my experience, once the event is dispatched, the handlers are executed synchronously in order of DOM binding, as specified above.